# Can't get intent filter working on Android - AIR app

Tags: android, android-intent, air, adobe, intentfilter

I want my app to execute when example.com is browsed to.  No matter what I do, I cant make this happen.  I've tried dozens of things listed in other questions.

Trying to troubleshoot, if I can get answers to these questions it will help a lot:
- Is there a certain permission I need to request in order to capture intents?
- Is there a way to query an app to see what intents it accepts?  So I can test that my manifest is properly being set.

Here is the config I'm using which doesn't work:

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
<data android:host="example.com"> </data>
<data android:scheme="https"></data>
<data android:scheme="http"></data>
<data android:pathPattern=".*"></data>
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you need two intent filters setup, or else it wont work.  You also need everything wrapped in an 'activity' block, which I didn't have.  Here's the updated XML that now works:

```
<activity> 
  <intent-filter> 
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/> 
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/> 
  </intent-filter> 
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
    <data android:host="example.com"> </data>
    <data android:scheme="https"></data>
    <data android:scheme="http"></data>
    <data android:pathPattern=".*"></data>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

If anyone understands why two intent-filters are needed would be great to know the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It's up to whatever app you're using to try to launch yours to use an intent that your application can handle.  If you're in a browser, and you click on a link that a browser can handle, odds are the browser is just going to handle that link instead of making an intent to see if there are any other apps that can handle it.

Try sending a link to your email and opening from there instead.  If you have set up everything correctly already, I bet you it'll ask whether you want to open your browser or your app.